# Repetir template em várias páginas com PHPWord

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos, gostaria de usar o PHPword para gerar as folhas de ponto da empresa, de forma que eu gere um único `docx` com todas as folhas de ponto para facilitar a impressão.

Eu pensei em utilizar um template, onde eu alteraria a tabela de dias, colocando manualmente os sábados, domingos e feriados, e depois fizesse um `while` na base gerando as folhas de ponto da seguinte forma:

- Pagina 1 folha de ponto do João
- Página 2 da Maria
- Página 3 do Sérgio...

Alguém com experiência em PHPWord poderia me dar uma luz? Um exemplo?

Comment: E o que tentou fazer até aqui? poste algum código para gente.

Comment: Até aqui eu usei apenas o exemplo do TEMPLATE, e consegui reproduzir a folha de ponto de um Funcionário em um arquivo docx. O problema é que, dessa forma, pra imprimir é muito inconveniente, pois temos que abrir todos os arquivos gerados.